# std::unique_ptr with derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I have a question about the c++11 pointers. Specifically, how do you turn a unique pointer for the base class into the derived class?

```
class Base
{
public:
   int foo;
}

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   int bar;
}

...

std::unique_ptr<Base> basePointer(new Derived);
// now, how do I access the bar member?
```

it should be possible, but I can't figure out how. Every time I try using the

```
basePointer.get()
```

I end up with the executable crashing.

Thanks in advance, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show a complete (but minimal) example of the code that causes your process to crash? `basePointer.get()` alone certainly isn't a problem.

Comment: @jogojapan I fixed my problem. I was doing some really weird casting with at least 5 sets of parenthesis. I'm pretty sure it was just something stupid, but I already changed it and don't remember what I did. Captain Obvlious' answer worked for me though. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If they are polymorphic types and you only need a pointer to the derived type use `dynamic_cast`:

```
Derived *derivedPointer = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePointer.get());
```

If they are not polymorphic types only need a pointer to the derived type use `static_cast` and hope for the best:

```
Derived *derivedPointer = static_cast<Derived*>(basePointer.get());
```

If you need to convert a `unique_ptr` containing a polymorphic type:

```
Derived *tmp = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePointer.get());
std::unique_ptr<Derived> derivedPointer;
if(tmp != nullptr)
{
    basePointer.release();
    derivedPointer.reset(tmp);
}
```

If you need to convert `unique_ptr` containing a non-polymorphic type:

```
std::unique_ptr<Derived>
    derivedPointer(static_cast<Derived*>(basePointer.release()));
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no memory leak when you do basePointer.release()?

Comment: @Marc Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @Marc The reason it is safe is because both `release()` and `reset()` are `noexcept`, so unless you are doing something very bad outside this function, the raw pointer will always end up in the derived pointer and will be correctly destroyed.

Comment: It might be obvious for some but please note that you are stealing the resource from the `basePointer` which is not always what you want in your unique_ptr conversion

Comment: @Masadow: If it's not what you want, then you don't want a *unique* pointer.

Comment: can't we just use a std::move instead of cast + release ?

Comment: Problem with the answer.
Yes, static_cast does also support polymorphic types. You should only use dynamic_cast when you're unsure whether the cast will work or fail (and in this case, test whether it returned null as you did).