# Right way to downcast a unique_ptr of a base class to a derived class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, unique-ptr, derived-class, downcast

I'm trying to implement an efficient and error free way to perform downcasting of a `unique_ptr<Base>` to a derived class `unique_ptr<Derived>`. Reading some posts I found that something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417848/stdunique-ptr-with-derived-class) can work (simple dynamic_cast). However, in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived) they say that to perform the downcasting properly the deleter has to be extracted and reassigned.

I'd like to know when it is important to extract the deleter and how should I implement that, since in the answer the just provide the template function with the `Del` type, but I don't understand how to use this type in an actual implementation.

EDIT:

More specifically, I do not understand what exactly is the `Del` type and how to set it in an actual example. I understand that it is related to the deleter, but I don't know how to define and use it. Since this is not clear to me by only reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived), I'd like some more explanation.

Comment: The second answer you've mentioned provides a complete and working solution.  So what is your question?  If you don't understand how a specific part of that solution works, please explain what you understand and what not.

Comment: Indeed I wrote that I did not understand what is the Del type and how to use it in an actual example

Comment: `Del` is the type of the deleter.  Note that (unlike with `std::shared_ptr`) the deleter type is part of the `std::unique_ptr`'s type.  By “how to use it in an actual example”, do you mean that you don't know how to *call* that function?  Because it is complete as written.

Comment: I mean when calling that function I have to define also the `Del` type. Where do I get it? is there a method of the `unique_ptr` that returns it?

Comment: As I've said, it's part of the type.  The compiler will be able to deduce it if you call the function like in `dynamic_pointer_cast<Foo>(std::move(pointer))`.

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh: You don't need to specify `Base` or `Del`, they can be deduced from the function argument. `auto derived_ptr = static_unique_ptr_cast<Derived>(std::move(base_ptr));` should do the job.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't understand that, now it makes sense.